# DropDownList not showing databound values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am wondering what is wrong with this code.  I am using `SQLReportDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("@profileName", User.Identity.Name);` to add a Parameter to the `SQL Data Source` in the ASPX page.  It uses `User.Identity.Name` to grab the current logged in user and passes that value to the ASPX SQL Data Source, but the `DropDownList` is not displaying any values and no errors are being displayed.  Is this even the correct way to specify a parameter from a ASPX based data source?

Even when I modify the `SQLReportDataSource.SelectParameters` to hardcode the value to something I know for a fact exists and does produce results which I tested via entering the SELECT query into SSMS, it returns nothing.  For example:

```
string name = "name";
SQLReportDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("@profileName", name);
```

I also tried grabbing the value from the `SqlDataReader` but same thing.  Where am I going wrong?

ASPX

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLReportDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SFGSConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [profileID], [profileName] FROM [vw_profile] WHERE profileName=@profileName">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="@profileName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="chooseProfile" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLReportDataSource" DataTextField="profileName" DataValueField="profileID" />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
SQLReportDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("@profileName", User.Identity.Name);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SFGSConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM vw_reports WHERE profileName=@currentUser", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentUser", User.Identity.Name);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    string memberID = reader["memberID"].ToString();
    int reportNum = Convert.ToInt32(reader["reportNumber"]);
    reportNum++;
    reportNumber.Text = reportNum.ToString();
}
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Why the hell am I getting downvoted?! God this place annoys the hell out of me sometimes. There are some great community members but sadly there are more douchebags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` prefix is not needed when you specify the parameters

```
<asp:Parameter Name="profileName" Type="String" />
```

and you can specify parameter value on `DataSource` `Selecting` event as below

```
protected void SQLReportDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["profileName"].Value = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thanks so much.  I started by removing the `@` and tried it but nothing, then I noticed your edit and then added the method as well as `OnSelecting` event and it worked.  Do you know why the code I had would not work?

Comment: You already added parameter in the ASPX and now you only need to set value of it.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to damith use to set default value like this 
SQLReportDataSource.SelectParameters["profileName"].DefaultValue= User.Identity.Name;

Comment: I tried that actually and got Declaration Scalar errors.  Maybe because I was using `@`?  Not sure.